# ODB Wiring: How to identify signal ground vs chassis ground?

Tags: electrical, hyundai, automotive-design

I am rewiring an odb port that was ripped out of my 2018 hyundai santa fe.

The issue I was having was that there are multiple same colored wires.

I was able to isolate each wire by using a diagram of the ecm plug and checking for continuity on the ecm plug.

The issue I am having is that becuase signal ground and chassis ground are part of the same circuity, I was getting continuity with both black cables at the ecm.

What is the best way to determine which cable is signal ground and which cable is chassis ground so that I can rewire the obd port?

[image: OBD Diagram]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your diagram, both ground wires tie to the same point UMA with no secondary tie-ins along the way. That means both wires are the same size and color with identical end points (UMA). From the diagram you could connect the 2 black wires either way and it would be identical. You could take a closer look at UMA ground point to see if it is indeed a single point or a single buss.

Comment: Ultimately success this by checking for continuity between the ocb wires and the pinout from the ecm plug, using a diagram of the ecm plug, I was able to know which pin corresponded to which wire.  The blacks were interchangeable.